# I want to custom serializer field, how can I do this?

Tags: django, django-serializer

I am using model translations for Django rest framework and right now I have in database 3 fields

```
title_en
title_ru
title_ro
```

and in my serializer I have `fields: ("title_en, title_ro, title_ru")`. But I want in my response to give something like this

```
data: {
   title: {
      ro: 'something here',
      ru: 'something here',
      en: 'something here'
   }
}
```

how can I achieve this? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
class YourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ['data']

    def get_data(self,obj):
        return {'title':{'ro':obj.title_ro,'ru':obj.title_ru,'en':obj.title_en}}
```